# how can i optimize the “Using filesort” in this sql

Tags: mysql

PAGE_VIEW_ID is PRI key.

sql:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT
  max( page_view_id ) AS pageViewId,
  max(NICK_NAME) nickName,
  max(createTime) accessTime,
  count( 1 ) AS browseCount
FROM page_view 
FORCE INDEX ( groupData ) 
WHERE COMPANYID = '24259' 
  AND DELETE_FLAG = 'N' 
GROUP BY 
  DATE_FORMAT( createTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H'),
  createTime,
  person_id,
  target_type,
  TARGETID,
  source_type
ORDER BY createTime desc
LIMIT 15
```

my index is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh6d4.png)

explain sql:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89gUa.png)

Comment: You realise that the result from this query is utterly meaningless?

Comment: why?
I want to find out the number of pageviews within an hour based on source_type,TARGETID,target_type,person

Comment: So why return the last nickname (alphabetically, and associated with a given company)?

Comment: nickname represents the nickname of the person viewing this content, I need to return it to the front end

Comment: No it doesn't. Nickname is the last nickname (alphabetically).

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain the business background clearly. In this table, personid and nickname have a one-to-one correspondence. I have grouped personid in the sql, which means that after grouping, the nickname of multiple data in each group are the same. I use max(NICK_NAME) nickName just to take out the nickname.

Comment: I just tried to remove the “max(NICK_NAME) nickName” line, but when I run the explain sql, it is still has "using filesort"

Comment: I don't think so. I see no functional dependency here.

Comment: Anyway, don't force the index, but make sure you have an index on some combination of (COMPANYID, DELETE_FLAG). And if company_id is an integer, don't wrap it in backticks.

Comment: I set up an index that is (COMPANYID, DELETE_FLAG, createTime, person_id,target_type,TARGETID, source_type).company _id is indeed aInteger type, I removed the quotation marks.

Comment: So, do you think it cannot be further optimized under the current business logic?

Comment: I would try rearranging the first 3 columns of the index, but beyond that, there's not much to optimise.

Comment: Ok, I will try it in this direction.

Comment: It does not make sense to `GROUP BY` an hour _and_ a second.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a query with an intelligible result:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( createTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H') dt
     , createTime
     , person_id
     , target_type
     , TARGETID
     , source_type
     , max( page_view_id )  pageViewId
     , count( 0 ) AS browseCount
  FROM page_view 
 WHERE COMPANYID = 24259
   AND DELETE_FLAG = 'N' 
 GROUP 
    BY dt
     , createTime
     , person_id
     , target_type
     , TARGETID
     , source_type
 ORDER 
    BY createTime desc
 LIMIT 15
```

An index on some combination of (COMPANYID, createtime, DELETE_FLAG) would presumably be useful.